# NullPointerException when using "class.getResource("/")"

Tags: java

I'm writing an application which is packaged in two Jar files: startup.jar and resource.jar. In resource.jar I have a java file(ResourceFile.java) has below code:

```
String dir = ResourceFile.class.getResource("/").getPath();
```

The application should be started up by running the "startup.jar"(two jar files are put in the same directory), but I always get NullPointerException at above code, I have also tried to change it to below code:

```
String dir = ResourceFile.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
```

Got the same error.

```
System.out.println(ResourceFile.class.getResource("/") == null);
```

print true.

I have looked around for a bit and I couldn't find a solution that could help me solve the problem.

Comment: You can only get files with `getResource` when run from a jar and they have to exist.

Comment: Why you expect that resource `"/"` or `""` should exists?

Comment: @rkosegi Depending on how the jar is built (if the zip only contains files, or also contains directory entries if I'm not mistaken) `getResource("")` can point to the folder of the package in the jar file of the specified class.

Comment: @LewBloch I meant "when run from a jar, you can only get files", which as it turns out is not entirely correct either, but you can't get `"/"` as a directory when the class path consists entirely of jars (you can if the class path contains at least one directory).

Comment: Just a bold guess, are you trying to get the current working directory? Try `System.getProperty("user.dir")` for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i expect to get the directory of the jar file, it should be OK to use "ResourceFile.class.getResource("/")", but i don't know why it always get NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `ResourceFile.class.getResource("/")` will return `null` when run from a class path that only contains jars, that is because a `getResource` returns `null` when something doesn't exist, and in a class path consisting of jars, root directories are not considered to exist (other directories may or may not exist depending on how the jar was built). If the class path does contain directories, it might not actually point to the location that you expect!

I guess you are looking for the location of the jar, which you can find with:

```
ResourceFile.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

That is assuming `ResourceFile` is a class in your own jar, and not some other dependency. Note that the URL produced by this piece of code points to the jar itself!

I don't know your use case, but you might want to carefully consider if this is really what you need.

Comment: Yes, When i print the class path of my "startup.jar", it only contains this jar file, where and how can i modify the class path? thanks.

Comment: The JAR from which you run the program declares a `Class-Path:` line in its manifest file. See the documentation for the `jar` tool for details.

Comment: @Hui what are you trying to do? If you want the location of the jar, use the protection domain. Otherwise, you will really need to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, thanks, protection domain can solve my problem, i'm trying to get the location of the jar file. just wondering why getResource return "null".